# PHP strip odd html tag

Tags: php

I am facing a problem when I use `strip_tags` to convent HTML to text.
The html code is

```
<img style="max-width: 60px; max-height: 90px;
            width: expression(this.width > 60 ? 60: true);
            height: expression(this.height > 90 ? 90: true);"
     src="image.php?s=d377256dd97b17e9bf0b1182743c95c2&amp;u=1&amp;dateline=1215813557"
     alt="DailyFX Forum Administrator's Avatar" />
```

the `strip_tags` can't work well, I want write some code using  `preg_replace`, but I don't how to match the last `>`, not the `>` in the style . Can you help me ?

Thanks
Gary

Comment: Unrelated: this is a very strange expression: `height: expression(this.height > 90 ? 90: true);` Now possible: `height: true;`?? Do you mean: `height: expression(this.height > 90 ? 90: this.height);` If you do, just use `max-height: 90px;`

Comment: @Rudie I think this CSS expression was made to get around IE6's limitations (such as no support for `max-height` property).

Comment: IE6? What the hell is IE6? If you use IE6, you deserve crappy, unreadable websites that fail and break and destroy your computer.

Comment: Stackoverflow has code highlighting. Indent your code by 4 spaces (or select it and press the `{}` button). That'll mark your code as code. There's no need to HTML-escape everything.

Comment: @Rudie Fair enough, you must be lucky enough to not have to support it.

Comment: @alex Nobody **has** to support it. I've chosen not to. Same for IE7. I mean this: if you use IE < 8, you don't deserve websites. And that's your own (or your organization's) fault.

Comment: @Rudie So having a percentage of your visitors have an untested experience OK with you?

Comment: @alex Yes. I don't care what my websites/apps do on your browser if you're running IE6 or 7. As long as you do, you're slowing down internet innovation. But that's another discussion. IE6 FTW!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your markup is invalid you must sanitize it before using strip_tags or any other markup parser. For this specific issue, you can try:
`preg_replace("expression([^)]+)", "", $your_html)`

I recommend you switch to using a stylesheet instead of inline styles so you have valid markup.

Comment: Yes .There is not short cut .It is only way to sanitize it before use strip_tags. Such as  preg_replace(array(''/<style.*?[^>]*>.*?<\/style>/mi'), "", $your_html)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a perfect example where a regex won't cut it (at least one that isn't convoluted).

Use a DOM parser.

Answer (score 0):

You *really* don't want to try to parse complicated HTML with a preg_replace. It's nearly impossible to get right.

Take a look at http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/ or one of the [other PHP HTML libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/best-methods-to-parse-html/3577662#3577662).